# ASP core HttpClient.Get From container to localhost site is failing

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, httpclient

**Given:**

- Windows 10 PC With Docker (linux container format)
- Local website in IIS accessable on the bare machine (no container) http://localhost/foo
- ASP Core DockerContainer which wants to access HTTP GET http://localhost/foo

**Problem:**

All requests to http://localhost are failing

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/foo");
```

Then I get

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error
>   occurred while sending the request. --->
>   System.Net.Http.CurlException: Couldn't connect to server
>          at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error)
>          at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.MultiAge...

Is this expected? I thought access to localhost from inside container should work.

Also other protocols like mongodb are working with localhost. So it seems to be specific to http connections form asp core?

Answer (score 0):

One question before: I suppose that the server you are trying to reach is in the same container, right?

**If yes:**

You should be able to connect from within the container using localhost.

The problem might be that this container doesn't expose the port 80 internally. Can you check the port internal port with "docker ps"?

**If no:**

In that case it means that localhost is used to connect to the host. My understanding is that it should not work.

Comment: The service is notr in a container at all. Its direkt on the same physical machine without any container.

Comment: Then, no, you can't access the host with "localhost". From a container, "localhost" is the container itself.

Comment: I tried it with a node.js application there it works. thats where my confusion comes from...

Comment: When you said that it works with a NodeJs application, what kind of application was it? Was it a server side call or was it a Javascript frontend like Angular/React?

Comment: Serverside Client Side should always work as the code is executed by the browser not inside the docker container : )

Comment: I agree with your comment on server side vs client side. But as I would not expect localhost to work to connect to the host, I wanted to make sure that we were talking about server side.